# BigQuery REGEXP_EXTRACT from URL - extract parameters values

Tags: sql, regex, url, parameters, google-bigquery

I need to use [REGEXP_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#regexp_match) on various URLs i have in BigQuery and extract different strings from them.

For exmaple, i have this URL:

url = 
`https://www.whatever.com/record-a-beautiful-and-professional-voice-over?sec_context=recommendation&context_alg=nodes&sec_context_referrer=search`

I want to use the BigQuery `REGEXP_EXTRACT` function and extract the string that comes after the parameter named `context_alg=` (presented after the first `&` in the URL).
Meaning - my output will be `nodes`.

(`context_alg` is a parameter in the URL and always has the same name)

So actually I need to use something like:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(url, "REGEXP that bring back 'nodes')
```

Thank you !

Comment: your question is not clear enough... please clarify with proper input and exact output you want... if you cant explain better then give two set of intput and two set of output respectively

Answer (score 4):

If you need to extract *all* parameters from a URL, you can also use [REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators?hl=de#regexp_extract_all) as follows:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(query,r'(?:\?|&)((?:[^=]+)=(?:[^&]*))') as params
```

This will return the result as an array (see [How to extract URL parameters as ARRAY in Google BigQuery](http://www.pascallandau.com/bigquery-snippets/extract-url-parameters-array/)):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this code. just adding one thing to save some ppl's time: If you want to grab a particular parameter's value,. use this regex expression `r'(?:\?|&)(?:(?:[myparameter=]+)=([^&]*))'`

Answer (score 2):

try below for BigQuery

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT(url, r'context_alg=([^?&#]*)')
```